# If 101 can be called "one naught one", then can 110 be called "one one naught"?

Tags: word-usage, numbers

I have heard lots of people say "one naught one" but I have never heard "one one naught". Is it valid or not? I have no idea; please shed some light on this.

Comment: I think it is valid, since you are replacing _zero_ with _naught_.

Comment: If you're in Britain, it's commonly said *one-oh-one*. *one-one-oh* is fine too.

Comment: "...the airplane will depart from Sata Misaki between the hours of naught eight naught naught and one one naught naught Tokyo ..." ; "all that piece of land containing by measurement naught decimal one one one naught (0.1110) of an acre " ; "110 (read one, one, naught); ..." ; Google it!

Comment: People tend to gravitate toward the easiest pronunciation. “one-ten” is so much easier than “one one naught”  and that’s why no one says it even though it’s not wrong.

Comment: I can't say that I've ever heard anyone say "one naught one".

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting confused from the pronunciation? As @marcellothearcane said, _one-oh-one_ is what I heard many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's okay to use naught for "nothing" or the digit zero. There is nothing technically wrong with doing it. However, I would caution in how much you use it. It's not common in the U.S. whatsoever. Especially for a numeric digit, they would just say, "zero", instead.

**Edit:** It's also very common to use the pronunciation of, "oh", for zero (ie, "one-oh-one"). Either zero or "oh" would be common in the US. Using "naught" is very uncommon.

Comment: We can (are supposed to) use "comments" to post our opinions.

Comment: @KrisK Ya I know. But some things are a bit opinion based by their very nature. This question has at least 1 upvote it told me someone plus the poster thought it valuable enough to need an answer. However, the fact is that here isn't a decisive answer. That's why I made the distinction about the US as well. It cant be answered matter of factly which means it should really be closed then if we can't ever ever answer a question in this manner. I find many that are done this way though (answered, that is).

Comment: @Kris However I've learned a lot about the customs in the short time I've been contributing here. That being said I don't see the point in only providing absolute and objective answers for *everything*. Grammar in and of itself is not even of an objectice nature, which is one reason I tend to think that way, but yes I have learned a lot more about the community customs since the date of that post. Some of it has been hard and annoying quite frankly (see the elitist/favoritism Meta exercise I posted). I still appreciate your position though. Ty.

Comment: @Kris: You're correct to the letter of the rule, but it doesn't quite apply here, Kace's answer is acceptable. The distinction Kace makes is based on _common usage and understandability_ (specifically in the US), not _grammatical correctness_. It's very hard to objectively prove common usage; but the answer itself is still pretty relevant because English is not exactly the same all around the world, which is the case words like "naught".